# Passing an enum as argument into a method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I asked this question earlier but deleted it to to not enough explanation.

I'd like to ask it again..

I have a Enum like this:

```
 public enum Call_Status
 {
     CALL_THIS,
     CALL_THAT,
     CALL_IT
 }
```

In my Controller, I'm trying to make my code dynamic, therefore attempt to pass ENUM as parameter like to;

Calling Method:

```
  bool result =  Method1 (Call_Status.CALL_THIS)
```

Receiving method

```
  public bool Method1(Call_Status status)
  {
       //Processing
       //I build a List<string> lstValue;

       //Now I'm trying to dynamically determine if this LIST contains my enum value

       if(lstValue.Contains(nameof(Permission.status??))) <-- I am unsure how this needs to be coded so I can do exactly this
       {
          return true;
       }

   return false;
  }
```

Comment: `lstValue.Contains(status.ToString())`? Or `lstValue.Select(Enum.Parse<Call_Status>).Contains(status)`?

Comment: Why you don't store a `List<Call_Status>`? Then it was `lstValue.Contains(status)`

Comment: Why it is a List<string>?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - my fault. The List<string> is a list of other values. Once I build the List<string> then I want to check if that list contains the enum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse strings to enums or use `enum.ToString` for the opposite way. But the first question is: why you dont use a  `List<Call_Status>` in the first place? Then it was `lstValue.Contains(status)`.

If that's not possible use either `Enum.TryParse`/`Enum.Parse`(if it's safe)

```
public bool Method1(Call_Status status)
{
     // ...
     return lstValue.Select(s => Enum.Parse<Call_Status>(s)).Contains(status));
}
```

or opposite way(easier and safer, no need for `Enum.TryParse`, but no validation as well):

```
public bool Method1(Call_Status status)
{
     // ...
     return lstValue.Contains(status.ToString());
}
```